# CustomListAdapter not working in some devices?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, android-viewholder, custom-lists

I have created a customized list adapter to show items in a listview. But this list adapter not working in certain devices. when I tried to log whether data is reaching the adapter, it is reaching there. Folowing is the code of my list adapter.
Please help:

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Schedule> ScheduleItems;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Schedule> ScheduleItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ScheduleItems = ScheduleItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return ScheduleItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return ScheduleItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;




        if(convertView==null){

            // inflate the layout
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listvehtemplate, null);


            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
          //  viewHolder.status= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cusid);
            viewHolder.textViewName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cusname);
          //  viewHolder.textViewAddress=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cusdesc);
      //
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }





        // getting Schedule data for the row
        Schedule m = ScheduleItems.get(position);
        if(m != null) {


            viewHolder.textViewName.setText(String.valueOf(m.getcustomername()));
            Log.d("log",viewHolder.textViewName.getText().toString());
            if(m.getcusid().equals("Finished")){
                viewHolder.textViewName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);    
            }
            else{

                viewHolder.textViewName.setTextColor(Color.RED);    
                    //  viewHolder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.xmark);







            }


        //  viewHolder.textViewAddress.setText(String.valueOf(m.getcustomeraddress()));

        }

        return convertView;

    }
    static class ViewHolderItem {
    //  ImageView status;
         TextView textViewName;
    //   TextView textViewAddress;

        }
}
```

Comment: Try passing context instead of Activity to the constructor.

Comment: Tried to pass context, but still same result

Comment: What devices are the problem ones?

Comment: what is the error message from logcat?

Comment: no errors in log cat. Getting the following log..

Comment: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1fd7f840 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2219d3d3 {com.mobtag.mobitagr/com.mobtag.mobitagr.MainActivity}} show : false

Comment: working in xiaomi redmmi, not working in htc, samsung etc.